# How to remove .action from URL without using a constant in struts.xml

Tags: struts2, xml-configuration, struts2-convention-plugin, deployment-descriptor

I am using Struts 2 convention plugin. I don't want to use any XML based configurations in my application. So, in this case, how how to remove `.action` extension from URL without using `<constant name="struts.action.extension" value="" />` in `struts.xml`? I am currently using `struts.xml` file only to remove `.action` extension. Is there any annotation to remove `.action`extension?

Comment: The default already allows for an empty action suffix; see [default struts.properties file](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/strutsproperties.html), specifically, `struts.action.extension=action,,` Is it really onerous to *allow* `.action` along with an empty extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't such annotation. You can use `struts.properties` or define a constant in `web.xml` like

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>struts.action.extension</param-name>
        <param-value>,</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```